# How to search and fetch json row data by key using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON object:

```
{

"1234A":{
    "apcdiv_staffname":"MOHD NASA",
    "apcdiv_staffimage":"http://localhost/jknsapc/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/product-landing-layout-thumb.png",
    "apcdiv_workplace":"HOSPITAL",
    "apcdiv_grade":"U44",
    "apcdiv_position":"PEGAWAI FARMASI",
    "apcdiv_ic":"1234567"
},
"1234B":{
    "apcdiv_staffname":"MOHTAR",
    "apcdiv_staffimage":"http://localhost/jknsapc/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/product-landing-layout-thumb.png",
    "apcdiv_workplace":"HOSPITAL",
    "apcdiv_grade":"U44",
    "apcdiv_position":"PERGIGIAN",
    "apcdiv_ic":"7654321"
},
```

I want to search and fetch json row data by using key. For example, if I search using key **1234B**, it will return the data belong to **1234B** key. From there I can proceed to grab the data inside such as apcdiv_staffname

```
"1234B":{

"apcdiv_staffname":"MOHTAR",
"apcdiv_staffimage":"http://localhost/jknsapc/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/product-landing-layout-thumb.png",
"apcdiv_workplace":"HOSPITAL",
"apcdiv_grade":"U44",
"apcdiv_position":"PERGIGIAN",
"apcdiv_ic":"7654321"

}
```

How to achieve it using jQuery? I tried to Google but cannot find relevan answer, maybe because my choice of keyword. If using PHP array, I can simply using this code:

```
$object_row = $object['1234B'];
$apcdiv_staffname = $object_row['apcdiv_staffname'];
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: `var object_row  = object.1234B`

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need jQuery for this. JSON can be accessed directly through javascript.

However if you want to use jQuery -

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '"1234A":{
    "apcdiv_staffname":"MOHD NASA",
    "apcdiv_staffimage":"http://localhost/jknsapc/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/product-landing-layout-thumb.png",
    "apcdiv_workplace":"HOSPITAL",
    "apcdiv_grade":"U44",
    "apcdiv_position":"PEGAWAI FARMASI",
    "apcdiv_ic":"1234567"
}' );

alert( obj.1234A );
alert( obj.1234A.apcdiv_staffname );
```

**More Information**

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/